# comparing a web table data using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have fetched the web table into excel using vba from  [this page](http://www.kieskeurig.nl/spiegelreflexcamera/nikon/d3200_body/prijzen/bezorgen/1052716#prijzen) now i need to fetch the first product and the position of a particular product(CameraNU.nl) from the pricing table. I have the following code for fetching the table

```
 Sub TableExample()
        Dim IE As Object
        Dim doc As Object
        Dim strURL As String

         If Range("B2").Value <> "NA" Then

        strURL = "http://www.kieskeurig.nl/spiegelreflexcamera/nikon/d3200_body/prijzen/bezorgen/1052716#prijzen"

        ' replace with URL of your choice

        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With IE

            .navigate strURL
            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
                Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
                    Set doc = IE.document
                    GetAllTables doc

                    .Quit
                End With
                Else
    Range("B1").Value = "Shopping Channel"
    Range("C1").Value = "Competitor Website"
    Range("D1").Value = "Competitor Price"

                Range("B2").Value = "kieskeurig.nl"
                Range("C2").Value = "Product Not Available"
    Range("D2").Value = "Product Not Available"
    Range("E2").Value = "Product Not Available"
    Range("F2").Value = "Product Not Available"
                End If

            End Sub




       Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

     ' get all the tables from a webpage document, doc, and put them in a new worksheet

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rw As Object
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim tabno As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

On Error GoTo Err1:


    For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        tabno = tabno + 1
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
        rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            colno = 1
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                If colno = 1 And nextrow > 1 Then
                    Set classColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("shopLogoX")
                    Set imgTgt = classColl(nextrow - 2).getElementsByTagName("img")
                    rng.Value = imgTgt(0).getAttribute("alt")
                Else
                    rng.Value = cl.innerText
                End If
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                i = i + 1
                colno = colno + 1
            Next cl
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -i)
            i = 0
        Next rw
    Next tbl



Err1:

Call comp

End Sub


Sub comp()
Dim i As Integer

Dim j As Integer

Dim k As String

Dim l As String

Dim m As String

l = Range("B2").Value
m = Range("F2").Value


i = 2

For i = 2 To 50

If Range("B" & i).Value = "Foto Konijnenberg" Then

j = i

k = Range("F" & i).Value


End If

Next i

Range("B1:h50").Value = ""


Range("k24").Value = j

Range("l25").Value = k

Range("B1").Value = "Shopping Channel"
Range("C1").Value = "Competitor Website"
Range("D1").Value = "Competitor Price"
Range("E1").Value = "Our Position"
Range("F1").Value = "Our Price"


Range("B2").Value = "kieskeurig.nl"
Range("C2").Value = l
Range("D2").Value = m

Range("E2").Value = Range("K24").Value
Range("F2").Value = Range("L25").Value



Range("K24").Value = ""

Range("L25").Value = ""
End Sub
```

If you run this macros you will get the exact result what I want but I need to compare the price without using that comp subroutine. Can anyone help me please...